# Getting data from URL is too slow in python

Tags: python, performance, url

I am fetching data from the [URL](http://paribu.com/ticker) but it happens to take about 4 to 5 seconds which I find to be very long. Here is my code:

```
import urlparse
import urllib2
import json
import sqlite3


class paribu:

#    def __init__(self):

    def getLatest(self):
        url = "https://www.paribu.com/ticker"
        #hdr is included due to an error in fetching data
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
        #ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr))
        ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr))
        #ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'))
        data = json.loads(ret.read())
        return data['BTC_TL']['last']
```

Any help to make it faster is appreciated!

Comment: What other code works faster than that?  Where is the time being spent?  Trace with your available system functions.

Comment: @Prune Bottleneck is the urllib2.urlopen row. I do not have any other code that is faster than that. I have assumed it is slow because I need to make real time trading decisions based on the bitcoin price data. I am trying to make some kind of a bot but the data fetching is not up to par. But yes I am a newbie.

Comment: How large is the dataset? How fast (Mbps) is your internet connection for downloads?

Comment: I suggest that you diagnose the speed issue, starting with some other manner to access the web site.  Code a trivial request (just the current stock price of some highly-visible company) in each of Python and some other language (search on line for examples in Java, C, or even the operating system's commands).  Time the response to both commands.

Comment: Until you have evidence that Python is the problem, you'll need to diagnose the actual tardiness.  It could well be your Internet connection, or response of the server end of the transaction.

Comment: I am not here to say python is the problem. I just want to hear from the python experts that this is a "normal" way to fetch a data and I am not doing anything stupid or inefficient. Apart from code inefficiency, internet etc. is for me to solve.